# Is there a way to have Harmon.ie keep original modified date?

Tags: date, harmon.ie

When uploading a file from a drive/fileshare through Harmon.ie, is there a way to have SharePoint keep the original file modified date?  Looks like the default is to update Modified with the current date and time.

Thanks!
Troy

Answer (score 0):

The modified field you'd like to keep is an attribute of the file system not of the document, the Modified field in Sharepoint is a --system-- field that is set by Sharepoint server (not by harmon.ie) at the time the document is uploaded and each time it gets modified. As a result, the modified date you see in your file won't be reflected in Sharepoint. This is the reason why you will get the same behavior when uploading documents with Sharepoint web interface in IE.

----- Jean